# "My logins" popup can't load from profile edit page

Tags: bug, status-completed

It works ok from the main profile page, but shows this if you try to open it from the edit page.

[image]

Comment: Request URL:http://stackoverflow.com/users/popup/logins/undefined
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.